# save .exe with java from client side to server side

Tags: java, html, server, client-side, server-side

I'm using Java servlet.
How can I send an .exe file from html input-file tag to server side and save it in the server?
I'm getting it in client server by:

```
 <input type="file" name="file" accept=".exe"/>
```

Comment: Have you use Google to find an example?

Comment: I was able to find just examples in php.

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=java+servlet+fileupload&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:de-DE:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=&gfe_rd=cr&ei=eis5WaGSC4X_8Afyj5qIDA